# Programmatically get like count of a photo from Facebook using java

Tags: java, android, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-java-api

I am developing an andorid app which post some photo on Facebook, at the same time I want to calculate the number of likes of that photo from my android app.

For information -
I am using Facebook SDK and I have successfully logged in Facebook account and posted the image.

The method which post image is below

```
private void PublishImage()
{
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    //Here we set all the required parameters to share the image and build that
    SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
            .setBitmap(image)
            .setCaption("Testing Sharing Feature through java")
            .build();
    //Now we share the PhotoContent by adding the properties in instance of SharePhotoContent
    share = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
            .addPhoto(photo)
            .build();

    //Now we use share API to share the image
    ShareApi.share(share,null);

}
```

> How to calculate the number of likes of posted photo with java instead of using Graph API Explorer manually ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that without the graph API. Once you call ShareApi.share (), there is actually a graph API request which uploads the photo, and you will get likes from various platforms, your app has no way of knowing how many likes have been posted

Comment: I do not want to use graph api manually instead I want to call it with java

Comment: It will ultimately be a Java written code which will do everything. You'll use Facebook's Android SDK (written in Java) to interact with the graph API, and get inormation about a certain picture, with it's id